# lightning:container - 404 not found

Tags: lightning-container

lightning:container gives 404 error, but iframe loads fine :(

```
<lightning:container aura:id="Cont" src="{! $Resource.StaticResource1 + '/index.html'}" />

<iframe aura:id="Cont" src="{! $Resource.StaticResource1 + '/index.html'}" />
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Container</title>
</head>

<body>
  From ... Container.
</body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions, what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

==>
It is so strange, when I create another static resource with the same index.html it works fine !!!!!!!

Comment: I have right now same dobut... do you know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The "Lightning Container Component Isolation" section of the [LockerService and Lightning Container Component: Securely Using Third-Party Libraries in Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html) suggests that `lightning:container` is the way to go though is not explicit about the LockerService blocking a raw `iframe`.

And the `src` attribute is listed for `iframe` in [Locker Service API Viewer](http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/index.app?aura.mode=DEV) as being available...

Personally I'd just use the `lightning:container`.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use lightning:container but I'm running into 404 ... how to fix that?

Comment: @SuryaChandraRaoGandreddi Its easy to get the ZIP content wrong e.g. accidentally introducing an extra root folder; it sounds like perhaps that was the problem all along. Sorry about my answer - I mitread the question.